# How to trim a string to a symbol which is not a number?

Tags: php, string

Good day.

I have string when have numbers and other symbols  (for ex. `1412%2Fall` )

**Tell me please how to trim a string to a symbol which is not a number?**

P.S.:
*For ex. `1412%2Fall` result should be `1412`; for ex. `23422345Dc#5` result should be `23422345`, and other...*

Comment: Questions **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function of PHP:

```
$str = "1412%2Fall";
$match = array();
preg_match("/^[0-9]+/",$str,$match);
```

And you can find your result in `$match[0]`.

Comment: +1 for using RegEx but i think it's a far fetched alternative when you can simply do a cast

Comment: This will match non-digit characters. I think you meant `/^[0-9]+/`.

Comment: Or you could have just used `preg_replace()` with your first example :)

Comment: @billyonecan nope, that will result into `14122` instead of `1412` from `1412%2Fall`

Comment: @HamZa you are right that's why I used the preg_match.

Comment: @HamZa right you are. I thought the OP wanted all digits from the string, didn't see the two 5's in the second example :x

Answer (score 7):

Simply use `(int)` or `intval()` or `preg_match` it.
`(int)` and `intval()` are almost do the same job. But, will trim the zero(s) in the beginning of the string.
 Using `preg_match` can help by keeping the beginning zero(s).
**[Try the code below](https://ideone.com/facnkN)**

```
preg_match("/^[0-9]+/", "1412%2Fall", $result1);
echo $result1[0]; //output: 1412
preg_match("/^[0-9]+/", "01412%2Fall", $result2);
echo $result2[0]; //output: 01412 (keeps the zero)

echo (int) '1412%2Fall'; //output: 1412
echo (int) '01412%2Fall'; //output: 1412

echo intval( '1412%2Fall' ); //output: 1412
echo intval( '01412%2Fall' ); //output: 1412
```

Comment: Side note: If the string starts with one or more 0's, it/they will be truncated

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely do it with regex but this will also work:

```
$some_string = "321312mcvsdf";
$number = (int) $some_string; //321312
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `preg_replace('/\D/', '', $youstring)`